# Linq lambda join error

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have been following the book Pro ASP.net MVC 2 Framework, which I have found to be quite brilliant. But it's a real learning curve and now I'm stuck.

In the book you build something like the below, which allows for paging.

```
public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(0)] string cityzip, [DefaultValue(1)] int page)
{

var roomsToShow = roomsRepository.Rooms.Where(x => x.CountryID == cityzip);

var viewModel = new RoomsListViewModel
{

    Rooms = roomsToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
    {
        CurrentPage = page,
        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
        TotalItems = roomsToShow.Count()
    }
};
return View(viewModel); // Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply Model) 

}
```

I think needed to adapt this, so that I could do a join on the search

```
public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(0)] string cityzip, [DefaultValue(1)] int page)
{

var roomsToShow = roomsRepository.Rooms.Join(
                    roomCoordinatesRepository.RoomCoordinates,
                    room => room.RoomID,
                    roomCoordinate => roomCoordinate.RoomID,
                    (room, roomCoordinate) => new { RoomCoordinate = roomCoordinate, Room = room });

var viewModel = new RoomsListViewModel
{

    Rooms = roomsToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
    {
        CurrentPage = page,
        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
        TotalItems = roomsToShow.Count()
    }
};
return View(viewModel); // Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply Model) 

}
```

...but immediately I get an intellisense error saying - 
Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MeetingRoom.Domain.Entities.Room>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I obviously don't understand the code well enough to figure out what is wrong. I'm also feeling a bit out of my depth with this lamda linq stuff

Room is a domain object which is defined as:

```
   namespace MeetingRoom.Domain.Entities
    {
         [Table(Name = "Rooms")]
         public class Room
         {
            [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)] 
            public int RoomID { get; set; }
            [Column] public string Name { get; set; }
            [Column] public string Description { get; set; }
            [Column] public decimal Price { get; set; }
            [Column] public string Category { get; set; }
            [Column] public string Pcode { get; set; }
            [Column] public int CountryID { get; set; }


            public MeetingRooms.Domain.entities.RoomCoordinate RoomCoordinate { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

and represents my Room table. Do I need some sort of parent entity that would represent the join between the Room and Room-co-ordinates table?

The co-ordinates entity looks like this:

```
namespace MeetingRooms.Domain.entities
{
    [Table(Name = "RoomCoordinate")]
    public class RoomCoordinate
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, Name = "ID")]
        public int CoordID { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int RoomID { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Coordinates { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }  
        [Column]
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

The RoomsListViewModel looks like follows:
namespace MeetingRoomsMVC.WebUI.Models
{
    public class RoomsListViewModel
    {
        public IList RoomsWithCoordinates { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    } 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion based on the OP's further description:

1) Create an aggregate class that holds both `Room` and `RoomCoordinates` info:

```
public class RoomWithCoordinates
{
    public Room Room { get; set; }
    public RoomCoordinates Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

2) Modify your controller action as follows:

```
public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(0)] string cityzip, [DefaultValue(1)] int page)
{

var roomsToShow = roomsRepository.Rooms.Join(
                    roomCoordinatesRepository.RoomCoordinates,
                    room => room.RoomID,
                    roomCoordinate => roomCoordinate.RoomID,
                    (room, roomCoordinate) => new RoomWithCoordinates{ Coordinates = roomCoordinate, Room = room } );

var viewModel = new RoomsListViewModel
{

    RoomsWithCoordinates = roomsToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
    {
        CurrentPage = page,
        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
        TotalItems = roomsToShow.Count()
    }
};
return View(viewModel); // Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply Model) 

}
```

3) Modify your `RoomsListViewModel` class and your view to reflect these changes.

Comment: Thanks for that, it seemed to help, the application now builds and runs, but when I click on search to enter the List method, I get an error:
The query contains references to items defined on a different data context. The error occurs on this line - var viewModel = new RoomsListViewModel

Comment: I have added the structure of the RoomsListViewModel above

Comment: This is probably related to the DB framework, which I'm not familiar with. I think you need to somehow register the 'RoomWithCoordinates' class into the data context, but I can't give you exact guidance on this, sorry

Comment: I think you are right, I'm implementing the repository pattern using ninject to bind the entities to a repository. I will see if I can figure this out myself...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, in this code

```
var roomsToShow = roomsRepository.Rooms.Join(
                roomCoordinatesRepository.RoomCoordinates,
                room => room.RoomID,
                roomCoordinate => roomCoordinate.RoomID,
                (room, roomCoordinate) => new { RoomCoordinate = roomCoordinate, Room = room });
```

you're constructing an `IEnumerable` of anonymous-type objects: `(room, roomCoordinate) => new { RoomCoordinate = roomCoordinate, Room = room }`

And then, in the next line you're trying to assing it to a list of `Room`.

The problem can be resolved by initially creating an `IEnumerable` of the correct item type:

```
var roomsToShow = roomsRepository.Rooms.Join(
                roomCoordinatesRepository.RoomCoordinates,
                room => room.RoomID,
                roomCoordinate => roomCoordinate.RoomID,
                (room, roomCoordinate) => new MeetingRoom.Domain.Entities.Room{ RoomCoordinate = roomCoordinate, Room = room });
```

(note the class name in the lambda).

Comment: I am now getting an error on        (room, roomCoordinate) => new MeetingRoom.Domain.Entities.Room **Room** = room })  --- the error is --- 'MeetingRoom.Domain.Entities.Room' does not contain a definition for 'Room' Should create a new domain entity that represents the join, so consists of Rooms and Room co-ordinates tables / objects?

Comment: well, that was a wild guess about your Room type. Could you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to do in this action? In this case I could come up with a proper solution for you

Comment: I am trying to do the equivalent of an SQL select with a join on the Rooms table and the Room co-ordinates table. I have existing Domain entities which I have added above. I want to list these as search results, hence the paging code. Once I have that working I would need to add some sort of where clause in there to limit it to certain co-ordinates. Thanks for your help Zruty, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Then your RoomsListViewModel class need to incorporate the room coordinates information. Currently, you only have IList<Room> Rooms field, but you need to modify this. For example, create an aggregate class RoomInfoEx{public Room Room{get;set;} public RoomCoordinates Coordinates{get;set;} } and modify the controller accordingly.

Comment: I think I'll write what I suggest in a separate answer